# Comparing 2 Images and marking differences with rectangles

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Edit: Updated the code, the code below now correctly draws rectangles around multiple shapes, but still has a minor issue of sometimes creating multiple rectangles on one single shape.

I have 2 Images, that i compare pixel by pixel with each other and i want my programm to create rectangles around the area of difference (multiple rectangles with multiple instances of differences). So far i managed to do this with a single rectangle, so if i had multiple "instances", they'd all be in one big rectangle. Now i'm trying to make the programm create multiple rectangles, but run into an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

The Programm itself overlays the 2 Images being compared with opacity and outputs the resulting overlaid image along with the rectangles into a new File. Both Images being compared have a consistent equal width and height.

I'm calling the rectangles i want to be drawn "regions" within the code.
The Region List is being continiously updated while the comparison is running.

The first question i asked myself was, when does a point of difference (pixel difference) belong to a region?
My attempt was to define a "tolerance", so as long as the pixel being compared is within the tolerance of the last found point of difference, it belongs to the same region. I quickly realized that this doesn't work as soon as i have a shape in form of a giant U on my image, with the top points being far enough apart to be not within the tolerance. And now i'm kind-of stuck, because i feel like i'm on the wrong path.

Below is the code i have so far:

```
private void compareImages() throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img1;
    BufferedImage img2;
    try {
        img1 = ImageIO.read(new File(path_to_img1));
        img2 = ImageIO.read(new File(path_to_img2));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load the Images!");
        return;
    }
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gfx = dest.createGraphics();
    gfx.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.65f));

    //Compare Images pixel by pixel
    int sX = 9999; //Start X
    int sY = 9999; //Start Y
    int eX = 0; //End X
    int eY = 0; //End Y
    boolean isDrawable = false;
    boolean loadedRegion = false;
    List<Rectangle> regions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Rectangle> check_regions = new ArrayList<>();
    Rectangle tmp_comparison;
    int regionID = 0;
    int tolerance = 25;

    for (int i = 0; i < img1.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img1.getWidth(); j++) {
            loadedRegion = false;
            regionID = 0;
            sX = 9999;
            sY = 9999;
            eX = 0;
            eY = 0;
            if ( img1.getRGB(j, i) != img2.getRGB(j, i) ){
                isDrawable = true;
                if (regions.size() != 0){
                    //Attempting to locate a matching existing Region
                    tmp_comparison = new Rectangle(j, i, 1, 1);
                    for (int trID = 0; trID<regions.size(); trID++){
                        if (tmp_comparison.intersects(check_regions.get(trID).getBounds()) == true) {
                            // Region found
                            sX = (int) regions.get(trID).getX();
                            sY = (int) regions.get(trID).getY();
                            eX = (int) regions.get(trID).getWidth();
                            eY = (int) regions.get(trID).getHeight();
                            regionID = trID;
                            loadedRegion = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Update Region Dimension
                if (j<sX){
                    sX = j;
                }
                if (j>eX){
                    eX = j;
                }
                if (i<sY){
                    sY = i;
                }
                if (i>eY){
                    eY = i;
                }
                if (regions.size() == 0 || loadedRegion == false){
                    regions.add(new Rectangle(sX, sY, eX, eY));
                    check_regions.add(new Rectangle(sX-tolerance, sY-tolerance, eX-sX+(tolerance*2), eY-sY+(tolerance*2)));
                } else {
                    regions.set(regionID, new Rectangle(sX, sY, eX, eY));
                    check_regions.set(regionID, new Rectangle(sX-tolerance, sY-tolerance, eX-sX+(tolerance*2), eY-sY+(tolerance*2)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // If there are any differences, draw the Regions
    // Regions are 10px bigger in all directions as compared to the actual rectangles of difference
    if (isDrawable == true){
        gfx.setPaint(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i<regions.size(); i++) {
            int dsX = 0;
            int dsY = 0;
            int deX = 0;
            int deY = 0;
            sX = (int) regions.get(i).getX();
            sY = (int) regions.get(i).getY();
            eX = (int) regions.get(i).getWidth();
            eY = (int) regions.get(i).getHeight();
            if (sX>=10){dsX = sX-10;}
            if (eX<=img1.getWidth()-10){deX = eX-sX+20;}
            if (sY>=10){dsY = sY-10;}
            if (eY<=img1.getHeight()-10){deY = eY-sY+20;}
            gfx.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(dsX, dsY, deX, deY));
        }
    }
    gfx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
    gfx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
    gfx.dispose();
    File out = new File("C:\\output.png");
    ImageIO.write(dest, "PNG", out);
}
```

Below is the code that creates one big rectangle around all the differences found in the images being compared.

```
private void oneRectangle() throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img1;
    BufferedImage img2;
    try {
        img1 = ImageIO.read(new File(path_to_img1));
        img2 = ImageIO.read(new File(path_to_img2));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load the Images!");
        return;
    }
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gfx = dest.createGraphics();
    gfx.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.65f));

    //Compare Images pixel by pixel
    boolean isDrawable = false;
    int sX = 9999;
    int sY = 9999;
    int eX = 0;
    int eY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < img1.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img1.getWidth(); j++) {
            if ( img1.getRGB(j, i) != img2.getRGB(j, i) ){
                isDrawable = true;                      
                if (j<sX){
                    sX = j;
                }
                if (j>eX){
                    eX = j;
                }
                if (i<sY){
                    sY = i;
                }
                if (i>eY){
                    eY = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Draw rectangle if there are any differences
    if (isDrawable == true){
        gfx.setPaint(Color.red);
        int dsX = 0;
        int dsY = 0;
        int deX = 0;
        int deY = 0;
        if (sX>=10){dsX = sX-10;}
        if (eX<=img1.getWidth()-10){deX = eX-sX+20;}
        if (sY>=10){dsY = sY-10;}
        if (eY<=img1.getHeight()-10){deY = eY-sY+20;}
        gfx.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(dsX, dsY, deX, deY));
    }
    gfx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
    gfx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
    gfx.dispose();
    File out = new File("C:\\output.png");
    ImageIO.write(dest, "PNG", out);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] please

Comment: `lastX = j;` and `lastY = i;` is what you want? Aren't `j` and `i` inverted?

Comment: Frakcool i'm not entirely sure what you are asking. The for loops iterating through the pixels, the j is iterating through width (which is x) and i is iterating through height (which is y). For every y it first iterates through all x, basically going from left to right and then hopping to the next row.

Will post updates as soon as i have any.

Comment: What i want is not the "lastX" and "lastY", but have correctly defined rectangles in the regions List for the programm to draw later on.

Here's a simplified image: If i compared 2 Images and found several differences, this is what i want in the output http://i67.tinypic.com/jqgto3.png

Comment: @Frakcool i have found my Error and updated the Main Post's code. It is now runnable and my state is the following:

Img1 = http://i67.tinypic.com/2meu3co.png ,

Img2 = Blank white PNG with same dimensions as Img1 ,

Output = http://i65.tinypic.com/16bft76.png ,

Expected Output = http://i64.tinypic.com/8x36vb.png

Comment: @Frakcool updated the code yet again. I got rid of the lastX and lastY and just started defining Rectangles and using the .intersects function to see if the pixel i'm comparing is within an already defined region.

Now i'm running into the following problem: img1 = http://i65.tinypic.com/34hto3k.png , img2 = blank white of img1 with same dimensions, output = http://i66.tinypic.com/w8rwxh.png . As you can see, the programm made additional "regions" on what should be a single shape, i know why this is happening but don't know how to solve that.

Comment: *"i know why this is happening"* Tell me why. Also, please post a proper [mcve] (you missed the main method and the imports)